# Wildcard in route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route in my web.php:

```
Route::get('/firma/{slug}', 'CompanyController@company')->name('company');

Route::domain('{slug}.domain.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CompanyController@company')->name('company2');
});
```

And URL: domain.com/firma/firma-2 and firma-2.domain.com - this it the same page :) firma-2 - it's slug (or subdomain). domain.com - this is my main domain :)

Now, when I open: domain.com/firma/firma-2 - I see company view. It's okey. When I open: firma-2.domain.com - Iahve mainpage (main page = domain.com).

I need add to to this route wildcard:

company-name.name.com

How can I make it in Laravel?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? It's not clear what you need.

Comment: I need route for wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `'domain.com'` in your code must be the same as your domain name

the main page route should be written **after** the `Route::domain`

so check your `.env` file and set the domain in `APP_URL` and try this :

```
Route::get('/firma/{slug}', 'CompanyController@company')->name('company');

Route::domain('{slug}.'. config("app.url"))->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CompanyController@company')->name('company2');
});

// the main page route goes here
Route::get('/','MainController@main')->name("main");
```